# MySQL: How to get comment content and the post title

Tags: php, mysql

In Question and Answer system I am trying to get comment for question and answer and the title of that comment.

I have done so far and getting comment's content but now the issue is if the comment is on the answer it is not getting the question title. So how can I write query so it will get all comment from question and answer both and will get the title of the question.

Here I have done so far.

```
SELECT c.postid, p.title, c.type, c.userid, c.content, c.parentid, u.handle, u.email, u.avatarblobid, u.avatarwidth, u.avatarheight FROM qa_posts p
JOIN qa_posts c ON (p.postid = c.parentid)
LEFT JOIN qa_users u ON c.userid = u.userid
WHERE c.type = 'C'
AND p.flagcount = 0
ORDER BY c.postid DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Here is my table image and you can find `type` column is for Q, C and A question, comment and answer respectively.

[image]

Thanks a lot

## EDIT:-------------------------------------------------------------

I have tried to check conditionally but this code also not working.. I hope you expert will guide to to correct this code

```
JOIN qa_posts AS parentposts
ON qa_posts.postid=(
        CASE
            LEFT(perentposts.type, 1)
            WHEN 
                'A'
            THEN 
                parentposts.parentid 
            ELSE 
                parentposts.postid
        END
    )
JOIN qa_posts AS cposts 
ON parentposts.postid=cposts.parentid
LEFT JOIN qa_users AS cusers 
ON cposts.userid=cusers.userid 

JOIN (SELECT postid FROM qa_posts 
WHERE type=$
ORDER BY qa_posts.created DESC 
LIMIT 5) 
y ON cposts.postid=y.postid 
WHERE qa_posts.type='Q' 
AND ((parentposts.type='Q') OR (parentposts.type='A'))
```

Comment: So you have tree structure.  And you need to find out a property of the root node given a particular leaf.  The issue here is that you don;t really have your data set up in a way to effectively do this.  I would recommend this article http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ that describes ways to store hiearchical data in MySQL (or really any relational database).

Comment: Thanks Mike for great reference. However this is one of open source script and not my written MySQL. I am still learning. But this would be good help..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT * FROM qa_posts p
    LEFT JOIN qa_users u ON c.userid = u.userid
     WHERE p.type = 'C'
       AND p.flagcount = 0
       ORDER BY p.postid DESC
       LIMIT 5
```

Comment: @Artist but your title is null in picture how you will get them ?

Comment: That is what I am looking. Null is for the answer and comment.. but it has parent id and I want to get title from parent id.

Comment: @Artist..what error did you facing and give your table structure

Comment: database query failed when generating this page

Comment: I am new to all these and don't know how to create that.. let me try and get back to you

Comment: @Artist..can you make demo fiddle in sqlfiddle.com you can search it and update it..hope it will easy to understand...and helpful for you